# extras Bundle in Android Notification usage?

Tags: android, notifications

Although not documented in the [Notification Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html), looking at the Notification.java for Jelly Bean there is an extras Bundle with an EXTRA_PEOPLE key defined.

The type is listed as TBD, can anyone from Android provide direction as to what this may look like?  Do you expect this to be a list of String names, or maybe Long rawContactIds?  Will there be any recommended ordering (such as meeting organizer versus attendees, or a Gmail From versus CC)?

Are there any changes in Android 4.2 that will utilize this, or is this still truly TBD?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is filled out now, relying on it is risky-  if it's labeled TBD then they can change it in any minor release without telling you, any code depending on it is likely to break.  I wouldn't risk it for anything I was releasing.

If you want to test it out though, write an app that uses it and use java reflection to get the class name of the object and print out the values.  If its a collection class, repeat on whatever object it holds and let us know.

Comment: That doesn't give me much, since the contents found through the reflection would be whatever I put in there.

I could write an Accessibility app, since those are sent Notifications, and try and see if there's any existing Google apps that have started using that.  I'd have to use Reflection since it's a private variable.

Answer (score 0):

Still truly TBD.

(General rule: Avoid using anything that's marked `@hide` unless you really know what you're doing.)